# c - check for when nothing is piped to stdin

Tags: c, stdin, pipe

Basically I'm trying to check if anything is in stdin when the program is called, so if I've got another file called output that writes to stdout then
`./output | ./program` should work and `./program` should exit with an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In POSIX, you can use [`isatty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/isatty.html).

Comment: user611775 has a better answer. Not portable to non POSIX but at least relevant to the question. "is a teletype writer" doesn't answer if piped data is available.

Answer (score 3):

`isatty` checks for a tty, *not* a pipe. Use `fstat(STDIN_FILENO, &sb)` instead and check for `S_ISFIFO(sb.st_mode)`.

To check whether there is anything "in" stdin that you could possibly read, you use, for example `poll(2)` with an event mask of `POLLIN`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the OP wants to generate an error if the program is reading from a tty, so isatty is a fine answer. Both output | program and program < file will fail isatty.

Comment: Plus I'm not sure you *can* test for a pipe input.

Comment: @lhf: I just gave the recipe how to test for a pipe. (It does depend a bit on implementation alright. If the pipe mechanisms uses a temporary file like DOS does, then of course this won't fire.)